# Why Listview showing duplicate entries with custom adapter android?

Tags: android, listview

I created custom adapter to bind with listview but it's showing duplicate songs in listview. please check out the code and let me know if anything is wrong

```
public class UnfavoriteSongAdapter extends BaseAdapter

{

private Activity activity;
private ArrayList<Media> data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

private Context context;

public UnfavoriteSongAdapter(Context context, Activity a, ArrayList<Media> d) {
    activity = a;
    this.context = context;
    data = d;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}


GenreFavoriteClickListner genreFavoriteClickListner;

public interface GenreFavoriteClickListner {
    public void onFavoriteClickListner(int position,Media media);
}

public void setGenreFavoriteClickListner(GenreFavoriteClickListner genreFavoriteClickListner) {
    this.genreFavoriteClickListner = genreFavoriteClickListner;
}


public static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView textView_title, textView_artist, textView_time;
    public CircleImageView circleImageView_albumphoto, circleImageView_favorite;
    public ImageView imageView_play;

}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View vi = convertView;
    final ViewHolder viewHolder;
    try {
        if (convertView == null) {
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            final LayoutInflater inflater1 = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            vi = inflater1.inflate(R.layout.song_listitem_layout, null);
            viewHolder.textView_title = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView_song_songname);
            viewHolder.textView_artist = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView_song_artistname);
            viewHolder.textView_time = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView_song_time);
            viewHolder.circleImageView_albumphoto = (CircleImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.circleImageView_nowplaying_playing);
            viewHolder.circleImageView_favorite = (CircleImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.circleImageView_song_favorite);
            viewHolder.imageView_play = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.imageView_song_playpause);

        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
        }
        if (data.size() <= 0) {
            //viewHolder.textview_albumtitle.setText("No Appointment");
        } else {

            final Media p = data.get(position);
            viewHolder.textView_title.setText(p.getSongName());
            viewHolder.textView_artist.setText(p.getArtistName());
            long millis = Long.parseLong(p.getDuration());
            String hms = ReusableModules.getCalculatedTime(millis);
            viewHolder.textView_time.setText(hms);
            String isplaying = p.getIsPlaying();
            int playingid = R.mipmap.play;
            if (isplaying != null) {
                if(isplaying.contentEquals(Constants.ONE)){
                    playingid = R.mipmap.runing_music_play;
                }
            }
            viewHolder.imageView_play.setImageResource(playingid);


            ReusableModules.setFavoriteToggleButton(p.getIsFavorite(), viewHolder.circleImageView_favorite);

            viewHolder.circleImageView_favorite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (genreFavoriteClickListner != null) {
                        genreFavoriteClickListner.onFavoriteClickListner(position,p);
                    }
                }
            });

            final String finalUrl = p.getAlbumUrl();
            viewHolder.circleImageView_albumphoto.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    BaseActivity.imageLoader.displayImage(finalUrl,
                            viewHolder.circleImageView_albumphoto, SplashScreenActivity.displayImageOptions, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onLoadingComplete(Bitmap loadedImage) {

                                }
                            });
                }
            });
            vi.setTag(p);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    return vi;

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

move

```
vi.setTag(viewholder);
```

inside

```
if(convert==null){
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            final LayoutInflater inflater1 = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            vi = inflater1.inflate(R.layout.song_listitem_layout, null);
            viewHolder.textView_title = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView_song_songname);
            viewHolder.textView_artist = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView_song_artistname);
            viewHolder.textView_time = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView_song_time);
            viewHolder.circleImageView_albumphoto = (CircleImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.circleImageView_nowplaying_playing);
            viewHolder.circleImageView_favorite = (CircleImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.circleImageView_song_favorite);
            viewHolder.imageView_play = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.imageView_song_playpause);

           // here
           vi.setTag(viewholder);
}
```

and remove this:

```
      final String finalUrl = p.getAlbumUrl();
        viewHolder.circleImageView_albumphoto.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                BaseActivity.imageLoader.displayImage(finalUrl,
                        viewHolder.circleImageView_albumphoto, SplashScreenActivity.displayImageOptions, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onLoadingComplete(Bitmap loadedImage) {

                            }
                        });
            }
        });
  remove this    **vi.setTag(p);**
```

Comment: i know that he is setting tag after if block so how he is going to get tag, and please check the code OP has given

Comment: where is v1.setTag(p) in if block of convertView

Comment: I set Media object as tag because i want that object when i click on item.

Comment: when u click on item u get position and from that position u can retrieve item from arraylist

Comment: Yeah. you are right. but your solution is not working here.

Comment: did u try removing and adding both?

Comment: yes. did both. I checked arraylist it's showing unique items. but when i bind with listview using custom adapter then it's shwoing duplicates items after every 7th positions.This may help you to know more about problem

Comment: change vi.setTag(p); to vi.setTag(viewholder);

Comment: Yeah. it's worked but i did some other changes in code. thanks -- ankitagrawal

Answer (score 2):

Change in getView() method like this.

```
   viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
  if (convertView == null) {
        final LayoutInflater inflater1 = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }
        vi = inflater1.inflate(R.layout.song_listitem_layout, null);
        viewHolder.textView_title = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView_song_songname);
        viewHolder.textView_artist = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView_song_artistname);
        viewHolder.textView_time = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView_song_time);
        viewHolder.circleImageView_albumphoto = (CircleImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.circleImageView_nowplaying_playing);
        viewHolder.circleImageView_favorite = (CircleImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.circleImageView_song_favorite);
        viewHolder.imageView_play = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.imageView_song_playpause);
```

and remove this

```
 else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
    }
```

in last of getView() method

```
convertView.setTag(holder);
```

try this and tell me it works or not?

Comment: It's not working.  when i bind with listview using custom adapter then it's shwoing duplicates items after every 7th positions.This may help you to know more about problem

Comment: try this @DharmeshDhameliya

Comment: I tried this solution and did some other changes. then it's worked. thanks -- Dalvinder Singh

Answer (score 0):

Add vi.setTag(p) inside :

```
if(convertView == null){
 vi.setTag(p);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

set tag for view holder if view holder null. Add last line of code

```
if (convertView == null) {
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                final LayoutInflater inflater1 = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                vi = inflater1.inflate(R.layout.song_listitem_layout, null);
                viewHolder.textView_title = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView_song_songname);
                viewHolder.textView_artist = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView_song_artistname);
                viewHolder.textView_time = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView_song_time);
                viewHolder.circleImageView_albumphoto = (CircleImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.circleImageView_nowplaying_playing);
                viewHolder.circleImageView_favorite = (CircleImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.circleImageView_song_favorite);
                viewHolder.imageView_play = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.imageView_song_playpause);


                /************  Set holder with LayoutInflater ************/
                 vi.setTag( viewHolder );

            }
```

//check you data size getCount,its a good practice. not in getview method.

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    if(data!=null && data.size()> 0)
    return data.size();
    else
    return 0;
}
```

I suggest you to replace getview method and check you data once because your adapter code seems perfect.

Comment: when i bind with listview using custom adapter then it's shwoing duplicates items after every 7th positions.This may help you to know more about problem

Comment: I tried your first solution earlier and it's working. thanks - Nil